# What do the letters and numbers after an adventure name mean? (H1, P2)

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures

This may arguably be a two-fold question, but as far as I understand it, the whole coding system that WOTC adopted for the 4th edition is intrinsically connected with the worlds that were created throughout the campaign books.

One thing that I couldn't quite manage to define was the listing as well as the division of all the worlds that are contained in the 4th Edition books.

Only a few of them have I managed to enlist, such as:

- Dark Sun
- Eberron
- Forgotten Realms
- Neverwinter
- Shadowfell

I feel that there are many other worlds and this whole coding system is a way of separating the campaign and tools' books accordingly.

For instance "Orcs of Stonefang Pass" is a HS2 book, which I completely fail to understand what that HS2 means, as well as which world does that campaign belong to.

Some other examples are:

- Keep on the Shadowfell H1
- King of Trollhaunt P1
- Demons Queen's Enclave P2
- Assault on Nightwyrm Fortress P3

I can clearly see a pattern there for the previous 3 books, P1, P2 and P3, being each previous book a prequel campaign for the following one. Still, the P code is a mystery to me.

I could place a world to the for campaigns listed above, being all of them situated into the Shadowfell world, as well as "Death's Reach E1", which is an E1.

Well. I guess you get the picture. If you could help me out listing the worlds as well as getting the hang of these codes' meanings, I think it would be a great source for latter apprentices, just like me.

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Well-written first question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The product codes for 4e books have nothing to do with worlds. Rather, they say what tier the characters are expected to be: **H**eroic, **P**aragon, or **E**pic. The number after the letter is their publishing order, starting from 1, and generally means that they can be used one after the other to create an adventure series.

**HS** stands for **H**eroic **S**tandalone, a Heroic-tier series of adventures that are not intended to be used in sequence, unlike the H1–2–3 series — i.e., each adventure "stands alone."

You can learn more about 4e adventure product codes at the [Wikipedia article on D&D adventures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons_adventures).